# Jquery slide hide-show div with an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a banner which I need changing on a click. at the moment I have hidden the 2nd banner and currently banner 1 shows. When I click the arrow I want banner 1 to hide and banner 2 to show etc.. only problem I tried using html.

```
<div class="homeArrow"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/arrow-right.png" alt=""/></div>
```

i want homeArrow to be the click button to show next banner

but not sure how to connect to jquery...

This is JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/152/

Comment: have a closer look at jQuery's [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) functions, and add css-transitions to the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide / Show one Banner at a time:

```
$(".homeArrow").on('click',function () {
    $(".homeImage").slideToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/152/

Sliding from left to right can be achieved by a little more code in jQuery see: 
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

You could also use addClass/removeClass and make the sliding CSS3 transitions. This would greatly improve quality.

UPDATE:

Here is the left / right slidy.
HTML:

```
<div class="homeBannerContainer" style="display: block">
    <div id="a1" class="homeImage">
         <h4>Banner 1</h4>

        <img src="http://www.nostomachforcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/nsfc_scam_banner_50percent.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="homeBanner">
             <h3>My banner</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="a2" class="homeImage" style="display: none">
         <h4>Banner 2</h4>

        <img src="http://www.nostomachforcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/nsfc_scam_banner_50percent.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="homeBanner" style="display: none">
             <h3>My banner 2</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="homeArrow">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/arrow-right.png" alt="" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    $(".homeArrow").on('click', function () {
    $('.homeImage').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    });

});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/174/

Comment: i thought you all would assume it would slide left and right... its a banner

Comment: why does it glitch? :/

Comment: it doesnt glitch, it's a basic example. if you want the first to hide before the second is show, you have to implement it in a callback. this site is not here to write code for you, it's to help you understand and learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59508/discussion-between-al123-and-fonzy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [show/hide](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function provided by jquery and even give it an animation.

Just give the banners a selector and use the [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Comment: i want a slide effect, not just show and hide... any chance to show on js fiddle

Comment: use .on('click', function ... instead of .click

Comment: Here I have updated the fiddle you have sent before http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/172/ with the animation you wanted. Just click on the arrow

Comment: what if i want it to go side to side, rather than up and down

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
function change(){
    $("#firstbanner").toggle();
    $("#secondbanner").toggle();
}
```

In HTML:

```
<button onclick="change()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($('#Banner2Home').is(":visible")) {

    $('#Banner2Home').hide();

} else {

    $('#Banner2Home').show();

}

return false;
```