# Jquery slider goes down how to make it go horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

at the moment I have hidden the 2nd banner and currently banner 1 shows. When I click the arrow I want banner 1 to hide and banner 2 to show coming in from the right hand side.

at the moment it comes from the bottom using this:

```
  $(".homeArrow").on('click', function () {
$('.homeImage').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
});

});
```

this is the JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/174/

How do i get the slider moving horizontal rather than verticle.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "moving horizontal rather than verticle"? It seems to work..

Comment: at the moments it slides from the bottom. because this will be a banner on top of my page i want it to move side to side rather than up and down

Comment: it's rather rude to take my answer to your question, not accept it and post it as a question again because you aren't able to use google or the links I provided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362589/jquery-slide-hide-show-div-with-an-image/25362796#25362796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set in this class `homeImage` `float:left` and clear float in this `homeArrow`:

```
.homeImage{
    float: left;
}
.homeArrow{
    clear: left;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/183/)

Comment: hi alex. i have done what you said, but can you have a look at my slider and tell me why its doing what its doing http://thenandnow.anytimeafter9.co.uk/  for some reason it doesnt slide rather jumps

Comment: Don't toggle entire banner. You can create a container for img and text and toggle this.

Comment: HI alex, i have done what you said added toggle around the container but it doesn't show at all now. thenandnow.anytimeafter9.co.uk

Comment: You can't have same id. ID must be unique. You have to set `display:none` in this class `homeImage`. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/188/

Comment: i have updated the code, but now the 2nd banner comes in from the bottom and not the side: thenandnow.anytimeafter9.co.uk

Comment: You don't use at all my solution. If you use what i suggest in my first fiddle you don't have a problem.

Comment: i have i wrapped the text and image to the container imageHome1. i used the js fiddle code. why what have i done wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the elements beside each other, on the same line. One way would be to set `.homeImage` to `display: inline`.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/8a7GL/181/